# Where does filterContentForSearchText:scope: method come from?

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

Recently, I noticed that `filterContentForSearchText:scope:` appeared in multiple tutorials regarding how to implement a search bar.

However, I looked up the references of both `UISearchDisplayDelegate and UISearchBarDelegate`. I found this `filterContentForSearchText:scope:` is neither a required nor an optional method.

I wondered if `filterContentForSearchText:scope:` is just a conventional method name for filtering search results?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is only convention for a common method called from the `UISearchDisplayDelegate` methods

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString;
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption;
```

The current ["Simple UISearchBar with State Restoration"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html)
sample project from Apple does *not* use this convention:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSString *scope;

    NSInteger selectedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];
    if (selectedScopeButtonIndex > 0)
    {
        scope = [[APLProduct deviceTypeNames] objectAtIndex:(selectedScopeButtonIndex - 1)];
    }

    [self updateFilteredContentForProductName:searchString type:scope];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```