# Swift - Detect text enter on UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

How do I detect when a user types into a `UISearchBar`? Should be really easy. Cannot find any help in the [Class Reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarShouldBeginEditing:)
Is not this supposed to print?

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool{
    println("Started Editin'...")
    return true
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `UISearchBarDelegate`?

Answer (score 1):

That would be because it is the responsibility of the `UISearchBarDelegate` to inform you of the text changing in a `UISearchBar`.

[UISearchBarDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have a good question, I struggled with a similar one in the past. @thatidiotguy is correct, you're going to need to implement the `UISearchBarDelegate` in order to be notified.

I believe the method that you're looking for is: `filterContentForSearchText`. It's a UISearchBarDelegate method that will send all the text in the box to this method each time you type or delete a character.

This S.O. question may shed a little more light on your question: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199678/where-does-filtercontentforsearchtextscope-method-come-from)

Best of luck!

Kyle

Comment: Can you suggest how the method works? With Code example, if possible.

Comment: The code examples can be rather in-depth, can I refer you to this tutorial? It will help you get the full idea, in context: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

Please let me know if you have any other questions.